# Map Error In python

Tags: python, mapping

```
def mapTarget(target):
    if target == 0:
        return 'setosa'
    if target == 1:
        return 'versicolor'
    if target == 2 :
        return 'virgincia'



ir = load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(ir['data'], columns = ir['feature_names'])
df['target'] = ir['target']
df['target_name'] = map(mapTarget,df['target'])
print(df)
```

**Python 3.x**
In the above program i'm trying to map the target value with the target name in the iris dataset. But it always return something like  **map object at 0x000000001466DD68**

Comment: In Python-3.x, a `map` is *not* calculated directly, it is done *lazily*. You better use `df['target_name'] = df['target'].apply(mapTarget)` for instance.

Comment: Have you tried `df['target_name'] = list(map(mapTarget,df['target']))`

Comment: You also need to put your python version in

Comment: And also print what your df is after this line `df = pd.DataFrame(ir['data'], columns = ir['feature_names'])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python map is a generator. To turn it into a list, simply change

```
df['target_name'] = map(mapTarget,df['target'])
```

to

```
df['target_name'] = list(map(mapTarget,df['target']))
```

Comment: Thank you @Daniel. I got that. That's a simple data structure.

Comment: If this answered your question please accept as the answer. Otherwise, are there any other errors which you have?

Comment: `map` is *not* a generator, but it is an iterator.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, the `map` function returns an *iterable*. This means that it is more lightweight and still allows you to iterate through the objects.

if you want to convert it to a list, you can call the `list` function. This is very easy. You can just change this line

```
df['target_name'] = map(mapTarget,df['target'])
```

to

```
df['target_name'] = list(map(mapTarget,df['target']))
```

However, if you only wish to iterate through the map and not print it out, you might as well keep it as a map object because it will be faster and cleaner.